# android can I get access to file on /data/user

Tags: android, share

I have an app that "shares" files, is showing properly if the user wants to "share" using the file explorer, I get files in this format:

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads/Getting Started.pdf

but when "sharing" from an app like MS word, I get this path:

> /data/user/0/com.microsoft.office.word/files/tempOffice/Share/7783958e-e851-4774-b28f-818e614b5991/Letteron.docx

So the question is, how do I access that file .docx

Apps like Gmail can add this as an attachment, so they are getting access to the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the actual .docx file?

If I'm understanding you correctly you may need to download the file first. Google has documentation for an API that can download files straight from Drive, which should come in the format you need.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads

According to the documentation, the standard syntax is:

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

But of course, refer to the documentation I linked above to figure out syntax for pdfs, word documents, etc.

Comment: hi, yes is the actual .docx file, so google uploads this file? then what Gmail "shares" is the server file? is not the on the device? thanks

Comment: @MaKo Seems like it. Google saves the file server side so you'll need to download it from their servers. Refer to the documentation

Comment: Look at my edited answer. If I helped you at all, shoot me an upvote!